# where clause on a nested document

Tags: laravel, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a nested document like this :

```
{
   "_id":ObjectId("598577f3acb9ee0c3b3e7199"),
   "shenase":"12300",
   "name":"ff",
   "vehicle":"van",
   "locations":[
      {
         "time":"12:16:59",
         "date":"12/05/1396",
         "latiude":35.7380266088257,
         "langtiude":51.5072907224076
      },
      {
         "time":"12:17:00",
         "date":"13/05/1396",
         "latiude":35.7380266088257,
         "langtiude":51.5072907224076
      },
      {
         "time":"12:17:02",
         "date":"14/05/1396",
         "latiude":35,
         "langtiude":51.5074229552436
      }
   ]
}
```

Now I want to make a where clause query like this but I dont know who should I do this .

here is the code that I tried but unsuccessful .

```
$locations = DB::collection('mycollection')->where("locations.latiude", "=", 35)->get();
```

Comment: what is this mycollection ?

Comment: can you send what output you need,example

Comment: @VirajAmarasinghe mycollection is the name of my mongodb collection.

Comment: @vicky $locations = DB::collection('mycollection')::select('name')->where("locations.latiude", "=", 35)->get();                                                             This will be the output :: ff

Comment: @NimishaRevi are you getting data from mycollection now ?

Comment: @VirajAmarasinghe yes